# Place image behind text in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'd like to put am image in a certain position on the title page in beamer. I also don't want it to interrupt the text flow, i.. I want the image to appear "behind" the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Redefine the `background` (or `background canvas`) templates to include your image; using TikZ you can place it in a `\node` and control its attributes (e.g., position, opacity):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{The Subtitle}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
        \node[opacity=0.1] at (current page.center)%
            {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};%
}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
        \node[opacity=0.1] at (current page.center)%
            {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};%
}
```

in the preamble, causes the background image to appear in all the frames.